# Отсутствует файл правил обмена Tr77_81.xml

Tags: 1с

Отсутствует файл правил обмена Tr77_81.xml, в папке ExtForms его нет. Подскажите где скачать, уже все облазил. Торговля и склад 9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно файлы правил обмена идут вместе с обновлениями как для ТиС (для платформы 7.7) так и для УТ (для платформы 8.1(2,3)). 
Если после установки обновления ТиС в каталоге ExtForms нет файла правил обмена, значит обновление скорее всего скачано не с оф. сайта.
Можно посмотреть в каталоге с установленным обновлением для соответствующей версии УТ в \users\'имя пользователя'\ApplicationData\1C\trade(base)\'версия УТ'\Conv9_2... 
С последними версиями УТ идут правила уже для платформы 8.2 (собственно и имя файла будет Tr77_82.xml)